# Not ideal accuracy in implementing Resnet in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, resnet

I'm a beginner in deep learning and I recently tried to implement 34 layer Residual Neural Network. I trained the neural network with CIFAR-10 images but the testing accuracy was not as high as expected, about 65%, like the following screenshot.

[Testing accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF6rP.png)

Basically, the way I implemented the residual block was as following:

For residual blocks without dimension increase, it was as the following sample:

```
"""
    Convolution Layers 1, Sub Unit 1
"""

conv_weights_1_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,64,64]),dtype=tf.float32)
conv_1_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_1_1, conv_weights_1_2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")

axis = list(range(len(conv_1_2.get_shape()) - 1))
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv_1_2, axis)

beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(conv_1_2.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)
gamma = tf.Variable(tf.ones(conv_1_2.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)

conv_1_2 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(conv_1_2, mean, variance, beta, gamma, 0.001)

conv_1_2 = tf.nn.relu(conv_1_2)

conv_weights_1_3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,64,64]),dtype=tf.float32)
conv_1_3 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_1_2, conv_weights_1_3, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")

axis = list(range(len(conv_1_3.get_shape()) - 1))
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv_1_3, axis)

beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(conv_1_3.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)
gamma = tf.Variable(tf.ones(conv_1_3.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)

conv_1_3 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(conv_1_3, mean, variance, beta, gamma, 0.001)

conv_1_3 = conv_1_3 + conv_1_1

conv_1_3 = tf.nn.relu(conv_1_3)
```

For blocks with dimension increase, it was like following:

```
"""
    Convolution Layers 3 starts here.
    Convolution Layers 3, Sub Unit 0
"""

conv_weights_3_0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,128,256]),dtype=tf.float32)
conv_3_0 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_2_out, conv_weights_3_0, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")

axis = list(range(len(conv_3_0.get_shape()) - 1))
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv_3_0, axis)

beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(conv_3_0.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)
gamma = tf.Variable(tf.ones(conv_3_0.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)

conv_3_0 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(conv_3_0, mean, variance, beta, gamma, 0.001)

conv_3_0 = tf.nn.relu(conv_3_0)

conv_weights_3_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,256,256]),dtype=tf.float32)
conv_3_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_3_0, conv_weights_3_1, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")

axis = list(range(len(conv_3_1.get_shape()) - 1))
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv_3_1, axis)

beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(conv_3_1.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)
gamma = tf.Variable(tf.ones(conv_3_1.get_shape()[-1:]),dtype=tf.float32)

conv_3_1 = tf.nn.batch_normalization(conv_3_1, mean, variance, beta, gamma, 0.001)

conv_weights_3_pre = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1,1,128,256]),dtype=tf.float32,trainable=False)
conv_3_pre = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_2_out, conv_weights_3_pre, strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")

axis = list(range(len(conv_3_pre.get_shape()) - 1))
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(conv_3_pre, axis)

conv_3_pre = tf.nn.batch_normalization(conv_3_pre, mean, variance, None, None, 0.001)

conv_3_1 = conv_3_1 + conv_3_pre

conv_3_1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_3_1)
```

I trained with all 50000 training images from CIFAR-10 using AdamOptimizer with learning rate of 0.001 and tested using those 10000 testing images. In the graph, the training was almost 1000 epochs, each epoch having 500 batches (100 images per batch). Before each epoch, I shuffled all the 50000 training images. Again, for a very long time till it finished, the testing accuracy almost stayed at about 65%.

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/freegyp/my-implementation-of-ResNet-in-Tensorflow. Was there anything wrong with my implementation? I'm looking forward to any suggestions of improving my implementation.

Comment: why did you pick avg_pooling on this line instead of max_pooling?
```663: c_pre = tf.nn.avg_pool(conv_4_out, ksize=[1,1,1,1], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")```

Comment: I also can't find your regularization.  The tensorflow team shows many examples that use dropout.  I'd suggest adding

```keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)\n
fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob)```

at about line 668 just after fc1 is calculated and then use fc1_drop afterwards.  You'll have to set **keep_prob** to something like 0.5 during training and exactly 1.0 for induction.

Comment: Is your training accuracy where you want your testing accuracy to be? If so you might want to consider adding regularization, if not you might want to look at other parts of the network like learning rate.

Comment: @wontonimo Thank you so much. I am trying with your suggestion and will get back with the new result.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz Thank you so much. You are right, I have to look at the training accuracy also. I added a dropout this time and I'm also looking at the training accuracy.